# Como aplico polimorfismo a un conjunto de datos

Tags: c#

con la siguiente duda,
quiero aplicar polimorfismo a lo siguientes datos:

Vendedor: celular, lista de clientes, carro

Secretaria: aumento, fax, celular

Jefe: Lista de vendedores, aumento, carro

código:

```
public abstract class Empleado
{
    public string[] Item = new string[] { };
    public abstract string Comportamiento();
}

public class Vendedor : Empleado
{
    public Vendedor(string[] item)
    {
        this.Item = item;
    }
    public override string Comportamiento()
    {
        string Comportamiento="El vendedor tiene :"+this.Item;
        return Comportamiento;
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Empleado[] empleados = new Empleado[3];
        empleados[0] = new Vendedor(new string[] { "Carro", "Lista de clientes", "Celular"});
    for(int i=0; i<empleados.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(empleados[i].Comportamiento());
    }
    Console.Write("Press any key to exit :v");
    Console.ReadKey();
  }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No termino de entender donde queres aplicar polimorfismo

Comment: Si ya gane una medalla :D y bueno veras quiero implementar el polimorfismo en cada una de los empleados ya que tienen cosas en común, en el código solo tengo al vendedor pero luego agregaré a los otros dos, pero no se como seria la manera mas eficiente de mandar los datos(cosas en común) al constructor.

Comment: Podrias explicar, en la pregunta (usa el boton [edit] y agregalo ahi), que entendes por polimorfismo, y que cosas pensas que son unicas para cada clase y comunes para todas?